# Design interface that now needs more arguments than before

Tags: design-patterns

Explaining usecase:

```
public class Course {
    Mathematics math;
    Physics physics;
    English english;
    String teacher;
    String schoolName; //Just want explaing modelling hence keeping
}

public class PhysicsHelper extends Helper {
    public void help(Physics physics, String teacher) {
        Course course = // create course
        help(course);
    }
}

public class MathematicsHelper extends Helper {
    public void help(Mathematics math, String teacher, Address address) {
        String schoolName = address.getSchoolName
        Course course = // create course            
        help(course);
    }
}

public abstract class Helper {
    public void help(Course couse) {
        // defualt set of operations to be called by all helpers.
    }
}
```

Now,i have a requirement something like:

PhysicsHelper has started understanding english as well, 
so now PhysicsHelper has method

```
public class PhysicsHelper extends Helper {
    public void help(Physics physics, String teacher, English english) {
    }
}
```

1. Is this the correct way of modelling this usecase
2. If in future more argument are needed by PhysicsHelper, should changes be made to help() method?

Comment: You better extends Course in the English and Physics course. Then you can call help twice. Once for each course. I hope that you don't want to add an argument for each thing that the helper understand.

Answer (score 2):

As @Charles Follet suggested, is better to overload `help(...)` method in your `PhysicsHelper.class`, than handle all possible subjects in one method. Plus, you can make `Course.class` contains only shared fields for all present subjects.

```
public class Course {
    String teacher;
    String schoolName; //Just want explaing modelling hence keeping
}

public class EnglishCourse extends Course {
    English english;
}

public class PhysicsCourse extends Course {
    Physics physics;
}

public class PhysicsHelper extends Helper {
        public void help(Physics physics, String teacher) {
        }
        public void help(English english, String teacher) {
        }
}
```